# Integer Factoring Algorithm Speeds

Tags: number-theory, factoring

Given $N=pq$, would $\frac{p-1}{2}$ steps be fast compared with extant factoring methods?

Comment: That is precisely as fast as trial division by all odd numbers (provided a single trial division has cost $O(1)$)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See for example [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization), where sub-exponential methods are discussed (note that this is measured in terms of the *bits* needed to represent $N$, not of $N$ itself).

Comment: thanks for the response. I see that now.